# AngularJS animation of children when parent toggled

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation

How do I animate the children when the parent is toggled?

If you run the snippet, you can toggle the container on and off, but the children do not automatically animate, they just appear. But when you type into the box, you can see them animating.

I would like the children to animate when the parent appears as well.

I'm only really concerned with the entrance animation, not the exit.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/wMNHyPMFEUZBjwAyNekj?p=preview

```js
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngAnimate']);
```

```css
.repeat-animation {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  line-height:20px;
  border:1px solid #ddd;
}

.repeat-animation.ng-enter-stagger,
.repeat-animation.ng-leave-stagger,
.repeat-animation.ng-move-stagger {
  /* 200ms will be applied between each sucessive enter operation */ 
  -webkit-transition-delay:0.2s;
  transition-delay:0.2s;
}

.repeat-animation.ng-enter,
.repeat-animation.ng-leave,
.repeat-animation.ng-move {
  -webkit-transition:0.5s linear all;
  transition:0.5s linear all;
}

.repeat-animation.ng-leave.ng-leave-active,
.repeat-animation.ng-enter,
.repeat-animation.ng-move {
  -webkit-transition:0.5s linear all;
  transition:0.5s linear all;

  opacity:0;
  line-height:0;
}

.repeat-animation.ng-leave,
.repeat-animation.ng-move.ng-move-active,
.repeat-animation.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:1;
  line-height:20px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.5/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.5/angular-animate.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div ng-if='show'>
  <div ng-init="items=['a','b','c','d','e','x']">
    <input placeholder="filter" ng-model="f" />
    <div ng-repeat="item in items | filter:f" class="repeat-animation">
      {{item}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button ng-click='show =! show'> Show Toggle </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need rules like `.ng-enter .childClass{}`

Comment: @charlietfl can you provide a working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this, Hope this will help.

```js
   angular.module('demo', [
  'ngAnimate'
]).controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
  $scope.items=['a','b','c','d','e','x'];
  $scope.show = false;
  $scope.search = "";
  $scope.toggle = function()
  {
$scope.show = !$scope.show;
  };
  
});
```

```css
.repeat-animation {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  line-height:20px;
  border:1px solid #ddd;
}

.repeat-animation.ng-enter-stagger,
.repeat-animation.ng-leave-stagger,
.repeat-animation.ng-move-stagger {
  /* 200ms will be applied between each sucessive enter operation */ 
  -webkit-transition-delay:0.2s;
  transition-delay:0.2s;
}

.repeat-animation.ng-enter,
.repeat-animation.ng-leave,
.repeat-animation.ng-move {
  -webkit-transition:0.5s linear all;
  transition:0.5s linear all;
}

.repeat-animation.ng-leave.ng-leave-active,
.repeat-animation.ng-enter,
.repeat-animation.ng-move {
  -webkit-transition:0.5s linear all;
  transition:0.5s linear all;

  opacity:0;
  line-height:0;
}

.repeat-animation.ng-leave,
.repeat-animation.ng-move.ng-move-active,
.repeat-animation.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:1;
  line-height:20px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="demo">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.5/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.5/angular-animate.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   
<input ng-show="show" placeholder="filter" ng-model="search" />
<div ng-if="show" ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search" class="repeat-animation">
{{item}}
</div>
<button ng-click='toggle()'> Show Toggle </button>
   
</body>  


</html>
```